# Enumerating network shared directories in C++ / MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, networking, directory

I need to get a list of directories shared by the current computer, and their shared names. How do I do this in C++ / MFC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [NetShareEnum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb525387(VS.85).aspx), supplying NULL as the server name.
You need to include Lm.h and add Netapi32.lib to the list of libraries linked,